# How Comparable and Comparator work in Collections?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

This code is from the famous Java SCJP6 book. I can't understand the difference between `title` and `d.getTitle()` in the `compareTo` method. How are both `title` and `d.getTitle()` getting and comparing values?

```
class DVDInfo implements Comparable<DVDInfo> {
    String title;
    String genre;
    String leadActor;

    DVDInfo(String t, String g, String a) {
        title = t; genre = g; leadActor = a;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return title + " " + genre + " " + leadActor + "\n";
    }

    public int compareTo(DVDInfo d) {
        return title.compareTo(d.getTitle());
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `compareTo()` method that you are showing compares the two objects by comparing their titles. That is, it orders DVDs by their title. A DVD with a title like "New York New York" will come after a DVD titled "Breakfast At Tiffany's", regardless of all the other fields in the DVDInfo object.

Therefore, `compareTo()` relies on the `compareTo()` method of the `title` field, which is an object of type `String`. `String` implements `Comparable`, and therefore has a `compareTo()` method that orders strings lexicographically.

The result returned is by comparing the title of the current object to the title of the given object. In my opinion, the comparison should either have been of `getTitle()` on both sides (which assumes the `getTitle()` will be overridden and takes that into account) or of `title` on both sides (taking the approach that if somebody overrides `getTitle()` they should also override `compareTo()`). But this is perhaps a matter of opinion/style. The bottom line, though, is that both of these are strings, and those strings represent the title of the DVD, and those strings are compared to each other to produce the positive, zero or negative value that is to be returned from `compareTo()` of `DVDInfo`.

---

Take two objects of type DVDInfo:

```
DVDInfo dvd1 = new DVDInfo( "Titanic", "Drama", "Leonardo DiCaprio");
DVDInfo dvd2 = new DVDInfo( "Guardians Of The Galaxy", "Adventure", "Chris Pratt" );
```

Now, if you run

```
int result = dvd1.compareTo(dvd2);
```

The "current" object (the one that runs the method) is `dvd1`. Its `title` field contains the string "Titanic". The parameter `d` is a reference to the object referred to by `dvd2`. So its title is "Guardians Of The Galaxy", and that's what the method `d.getTitle()` returns. Now it compares these two strings, and the comparison becomes equivalent to:

```
"Titanic".compareTo("Guardians Of The Galaxy")
```

Which returns 13 (a positive number, showing that "Titanic" is greater than "Guardians Of The Galaxy").

Comment: So when the CompareTo() method runs 'title' and d.getTitle() method will both retrieve the firs title which would be similar then how can they compare the strings if the first title is being compared to itself ?

Comment: @SamLot They are not the same object, so they are not the same title. And if the two DVDs happen to have the same title, then the method returns 0, this is the definition of `compareTo()`.

Comment: So lets say there are four DVDs  with the titles 'a','c','d' and 'd'.  When the method runs 'title' will have the value of 'a' in and d.getTitle() will also have 'a' in it .Isnt it so? If not then what values would both of them be holding in the first comparison?

Comment: @SamLot No, that's not correct. I have added an example to my answer of how the comparison works.

Answer (score 0):

In `compareTo()` method there are two instances compared. When you use it from the outside it can look like this:

```java
DVDInfo first = new DVDInfo("title1");
DVDInfo second = new DVDInfo("title2");

// compare
first.copareTo(second);
```

You can see the `compareTo()` method is called in "first" DVDInfo instance scope.

When implementing `compareTo()` in your class you will get the "second" instance as an argument:

```java
public int compareTo(DVDInfo other) {
     // 'title' is the local field (this.title)
     // 'other.getTitle()' is the title from the 'other' (second) instance
     return title.compareTo(other.getTitle());
}
```